# helm nested variable reference not happening

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I am not able to reference variable inside a nested variable in Helm.  I am not able to do this nested reference, I want to retrieve `app1_image` and `app1_tag` using the value of the `apps_label` variable. How can I do that?

values.yaml:

```yaml
  apps:
   -  name: web-server
       label: app1
       command: /root/web.sh
       port: 80

   -  name: app-server
      label: app2
      command: /root/app.sh
      port: 8080

app1_image:
     name: nginx
     tag: v1.0

app2_image:
    name: tomcat
    tag: v1.0
```

deployment.yaml:

```yaml
{{- range $apps := .Values.apps
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: {{ $apps.name }}
  labels:
    app: {{ $apps.name }}
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: 
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: {{ $apps.name }}
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: {{ $apps.name }}
        image: {{ $.Values.$apps.label.image }}: {{ $.Values.$apps.label.tag }}
        ports:
        - containerPort: {{ $apps.port}}
{{- end }}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The core Go [text/template](https://godoc.org/text/template) language includes an `index` function that you can use as a more dynamic version of the `.` operator.  Given the values file you show, you could do the lookup (inside the loop) as something like:

```
{{- $key := printf "%s_image" $apps.label }}
{{- $settings := index $.Values $key | required (printf "could not find top-level settings for %s" $key) }}
      - name: {{ $apps.name }}
        image: {{ $settings.image }}:{{ $settings.tag }}
```

You could probably rearrange the layout of the `values.yaml` file to make this clearer.  You also might experiment with what you can provide with multiple `helm install -f` options to override options at install time; if you can keep all of these settings in one place it is easier to manage.